# Check user authentication based on path in sonata

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

is it possible to check if user is authenticated to access the URl he requested. What I want to do is when user not logged in he can't see files by url.

example : [=> Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5M8e.png)

Any suggestions? Thank you

**Update**

**this is my access control:**
All access working fine for my application

```
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login-check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_USER] }
    - { path: ^/admin/rlsh/dashboard, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/uploads/media, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/profile/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/shop/basket/step/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/shop/user/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php restrict access to files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645196/php-restrict-access-to-files-in-directory)

Comment: thank u for quick response but i can't use my own access logic cause i have more than 50 bundles in my project and i can't go one by one and send a logic value to test with it i need something global and more secure

Comment: What is the difference between your `admin` and `main` firewalls ? 
Could you check your logs in debug mode (especially the security context) to have more informations of what is happening when requestinga media. 
Could you also add your `access_control` definition from the `security.yml`, maybe you have a definition overriding my answer suggestion :)

Comment: i add my access_control definition from the security.yml

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the main and admin firewalls I don't see missconfiguration for what you're trying to do.  To debug this you'll have to add the logs for a request to a media. Process as follow, from the root level of your project `echo '' > app/logs/dev.log`, then do a call to a media, and then run command: `cat app/logs/dev.log` and update the question with the output. Configure your monolog to the `debug` before doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be connected to access to your files, you could use a simple `access_control`, please take a look

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/uploads/media, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

A not authenticated user trying to access to your files will get a 403 forbidden response.

Btw you can customize the `path` with a regex and many others things, feel free to [take a look](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already have This path in my security.yml

Comment: So if you try to access a ressource without being authenticated you should receive a forbidden response. If not, could you please provide in your question the firewalls part of your `security.yml` configuration